# Print PDF file with variables from other file?

Tags: php, html, pdf, printing

I am wondering is it possible to print PDF file, and replace the blank spots in it with variables I get from my website, so output depends on the variable's value etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) to do what you need.

But in this case you have to know that you must create a pdf file from scratch and fill it in the way you want.

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();    // add page to PDF
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);    // Choose a font and size
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');  // write anything to any line you want
$pdf->Output("your_name.pdf");   // Export the file and send in to browser       
?>
```